# How to set fields in form JQUERY

Tags: jquery

```
function populateForm(id) {
$("form[name='application']").$("form[element='partyid']").val = id ;
}
```

I am trying to set column partyid in form application with value of id this does not work

Comment: `$(function () {
  $('#partyid').val("fgg");
});`  is this what u are looking for?

Comment: can you please tell me what about form application and what is fgg

Comment: There are *many* things wrong with just this one line of code.  Where did you even get this?  What does your HTML look like?  Maybe start with *any* introductory jQuery tutorial or examples?

Comment: this is the html <tr>
 <td><a href="javascript:populateForm(${parties.id});"><c:out value="${parties.id}"/></a></td>
 <td>${parties.partycode}</td>
 <td>${parties.partyname}</td>
 </tr>

Comment: can you share a fidler??

Comment: @DeveshBhatia: That's not HTML (not all of it anyway), that's JSTL.  If you're seeing JSTL in your browser then your application is *very* broken (and jQuery won't fix it).

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you don't chain jQuery selectors like that.  Just use a single jQuery object to target the element(s) you want:

```
$("form[element='partyid']")
```

Second, what is that selector even looking for?  `element` isn't an attribute that I've ever seen.  Without seeing your HTML it's impossible to know what you're trying to select, but it sounds like you want an `input` within a `form`.  So target that input.  For example:

```
$("input[name='partyid']")
```

or perhaps:

```
$("#partyid")
```

(Again, it depends on what your HTML actually looks like.)

Finally, `val` is a *function* and not a property to set:

```
$("#partyid").val(id)
```

Comment: can I do it this way $("#application").$("#partyid").val(id)

Comment: @DeveshBhatia: That's not a way I've ever seen, so I doubt it.  Why would you want to?  What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need like this.

```
function populateForm(id) {
 $('#partyid').val(id);
}
```

If this is not what your looking for please show us your HTML structure.

Comment: I am having my value on popup which I want to set on another form how will it come to now the other form using jquery

Comment: Your another form making me confuse - what it refers? Better prepare jsfiddle or codeped with scenario which your facing so that it helpful us to resolve your issue

Comment: first I call a popup from form named "application" once the popup is opened I click on the href the row that is clicked contains element that needs to be populated on the field on the form "application" how do I do this using jquery